# Does submitting TeX sources to arXiv increase risk of plagiarism?

Tags: plagiarism, arxiv, latex

It is mandatory that manuscripts that are TeX/LaTeX-based must be submitted along with all source files, which includes the `tex` document, images and supplementary files (like CSV files) required to generate the PDF.

According to [arXiv's TeX FAQ](https://arxiv.org/help/faq/whytex), this sort of submission does not increase the risk of plagiarizing content. They claim that anyone with *little knowledge* can extract the necessary files from basic PDF files and that verbatim from TeX document can be easily detected.

Now, taking this from the practical viewpoint, is it *really* true that this does not make plagiarizing data easier than the simple PDF submission? According to my knowledge there are many potential plagiarizers who find it hard to take vector graphics from PDF files. Eventhough it is technically possible it does deter many to an extent.

So, does submitting (La)TeX source files to arXiv increase the risk of getting the plagiarized?

Comment: I'm not really sure what the question is.  How could you possibly quantify "how safe"?  It's obvious, as you say, that there *could* be someone who is able / willing to steal text only if they have the LaTeX source, and wouldn't bother if there was just a pdf.

Comment: @NateEldredge To be direct, does it increase the risk of plagiarism? Thanks, just made the edit to the last line for clarity.

Comment: Slightly OT, beyond safety from plagiarism, there's also safety concerns regarding any comments written in LaTeX source.

Comment: You can expunge the comments with a simple script before uploading, so that is not really a problem.

Comment: @user2768 Yes, I agree with CaptainEmacs; arXiv provides a simple Perl script to remove all comments, so isn't much of an issue at all (I just don't bother to use it anyway).

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac, presumably it doesn't remove all comments, e.g., \iffalse...\fi, \begin{verbatim}...\end{verbatim}, etc., can all be considered as comment blocks

Comment: What is more important, protecting your paper from potential plagiarism, or making it easy to share your research results?

Comment: @jamesqf Agreed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> is it *really* true that this does not make plagiarizing data easier than the simple PDF submission?

The Arxiv doesn’t claim this. All they claim is that plagiarism is pretty easy anyway. The respective Arxiv text reads:

> There is no file format or other technological device that can protect you from [plagiarism]. At the very least, unscrupulous re-typers would always remain a threat. Postscript does not provide a barrier in any event: it is quite simple for someone with a little knowledge to extract any text from a Postscript file. Moreover a plagiarist who cuts-and-pastes directly from your TeX source is all the more easily detected, since the source is easily identified. We archive all versions of papers so that we can assist in any priority or plagiarism disputes.

---

> So, how safe is it to submit (La)TeX source files to arXiv?

For all practical purposes I would say it is as safe as any other type of Arxiv submission. I concur with the Arxiv that making a technical copy of your article is pretty easy anyway. Even re-typing the entire article and using screenshots of your graphics is a comparably easy task. Yes, the quality may suck, but that wouldn’t bother the plagiarist.

**The main challenge to successfully plagiarise is to use the plagiarised article and remain undetected – not making a technical copy.**

Comment: That's a bit more relieving. Did you submit LaTeX source in arXiv before?

Comment: Yes, ten times. Not that this proves anything.

Comment: No, I didn't mean that. I just wanted to get some clarity on bibliography submission. They stated bbl files should be submitted and `bib` submission is optional. It turns out that bib file is just not being uploaded. In the end, I had to replace the `\bibliography` command with `\bibliography{<filename>.bbl}` for arXiv to successfully compile it. Just to be sure, did I do it right? It's the first time for me.

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac: Huh, I've never had to do that.  But if it compiled successfully and the output looks okay, then you did it right.

Comment: @NateEldredge That's a relief. When I first submitted with only the bbl file and the original `tex` file, all citations were undefined on compilation -- intriguing. It looks fine now after making the change. Thanks, Nate and Wrzlprmft.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: (La)TeX submissions are as safe as PDF (and anything else, probably).

Scissoring images from a PDF is as easy as running pdfimages. Getting the text is as easy as running pdf2ascii. PDFs are in no way secure. To prevent plagery make sure you publish in a respectable journal - preferably Open Access.

Remember, if your machine can display some media, it must be able to decode it. Some formats may depend on hardware keys, which makes it more difficult to crack, but even so, the data is still present on your machine.

The point of *publishing* your work is to "stake your claim" to the work through peer-review.

Comment: Why do people downvote the answer?

Comment: @Mayou36 Because it does not answer the question: *So, does submitting (La)TeX source files to arXiv increase the risk of getting the plagiarized?*